# The rank of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Suppose that $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d:=\deg P$ over a field $\mathbb F$ of zero characteristic, splitting completely into pairwise distinct linear factors, and $B,C\subset\mathbb F$ are sets of size $n:=|B|=|C|$; the range of interest is $n\sim d^{2/3}$. Consider the matrix
  $$ M := \begin{pmatrix}
       P^{(d)}(c)\, b^d \\
       P^{(d-1)}(c)\, b^{d-1}\, \\
         \vdots \\
       P(c)
     \end{pmatrix}_{b\in B,c\in C} $$
(this is in fact just one out of the $|B||C|$ columns, the whole matrix has size $(d+1)\times n^2$).

1. Is it true that, *normally*, this matrix has rank at least $d+2-n$? Are there any reasonable sufficient conditions for $\mathrm{rk}\, M\ge d+2-n$ to hold?
2. At least, can one exclude (under some reasonable assumptions) the scenario where each of the last $n$ rows is a linear combination of the first $d+1-n$ rows?

Notice that any row $P^{(s)}(c)\,b^s$ can be made proportional to any other row $P^{(t)}(c)\,b^t$ with $t\le d-n$: this happens if $B$ is contained in a level set of the mapping $x\mapsto x^{t-s}$, and $C$ is contained in the zero locus of the polynomial $P^{(t)}-KP^{(s)}$ with an appropriate $K\in\mathbb F$.